# What are some common methods for calculating short term historical volatility (i.e. look back 5 minute time periods)

Tags: high-frequency, log-returns

I'm interested in quantifying the impact of short term price volatility on a particular strategy I'm running. So far I'm simply calculating the standard deviation of log returns, but I'm a bit unsure on where to take it from here. Additionally - any textbooks/further reading on this sort of thing appreciated.

Comment: What is the frequency of your data? It sounds like you're looking for realized volatility estimators. In general, if you have a sub-minute frequency it is often a good idea to consider noise-robust estimators, since price-data (TAQ data) tend to be noisy (for equities). Here, liquidity of your considered instruments, also have an impact on your estimates and sampling scheme.

Comment: I am using sub-minute frequency, thanks, I'll look into these key words.

Comment: For noise-robust realized estimators you can take a look at the *Realized kernel estimator* of [Barndorff-Nielsen et al. (2009)](https://academic.oup.com/ectj/article-abstract/12/3/C1/5061260) or the *Preaveraging estimator* of [Jacod et al. (2009)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414908001701). They both exist in a multivariate version and are implemented in the (very detailed and thorough) `R` package called *highfrequency*. They recently updated their documentation of the package, which is available [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3917548).

Comment: Reading their documentation will give you loads of references and applicable estimators besides the ones I've talked about above. I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. Much appreciated